# Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I'm trying to read the messages from kafka (version 10) in spark and trying to print it.

```
     import spark.implicits._

         val spark = SparkSession
              .builder
              .appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount")
              .config("spark.master", "local")
              .getOrCreate()  

            val ds1 = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
              .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")  
              .option("subscribe", "topicA")
              .load()

           ds1.collect.foreach(println)
           ds1.writeStream
           .format("console")
           .start()

           ds1.printSchema()
```

getting an error Exception in thread "main"

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources
>   must be executed with writeStream.start();;

Answer (score 37):

You are branching the query plan: from the same ds1 you are trying to:

- `ds1.collect.foreach(...)`
- `ds1.writeStream.format(...){...}`

But you are only calling `.start()` on the second branch, leaving the other dangling without a termination, which in turn throws the exception you are getting back.

The solution is to start both branches and await termination.

```
val ds1 = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")  
  .option("subscribe", "topicA")  
  .load()
val query1 = ds1.collect.foreach(println)
  .writeStream
  .format("console")
  .start()
val query2 = ds1.writeStream
  .format("console")
  .start()

ds1.printSchema()
query1.awaitTermination()
query2.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: so what's the fix?

Comment: I second the comment here. Can we get a proper solution here? Maybe a code sample? Thanks!

Comment: See @Rajeev answer, `awaitTermination` should be called after `start`

Answer (score 8):

i fixed issue by using following code.

```
 val df = session
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", brokers)
  .option("subscribe", "streamTest2")
  .load();

    val query = df.writeStream
  .outputMode("append")
  .format("console")
  .start()
query.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 7):

I struggled a lot with this issue. I tried each of suggested solution from various blog.
But I my case there are few statement in between calling start() on query and finally at last i was calling awaitTerminate() function that cause this.

Please try in this fashion, It is perfectly working for me.
Working example:

```
val query = df.writeStream
      .outputMode("append")
      .format("console")
      .start().awaitTermination();
```

If you write in this way that will cause exception/ error:

```
val query = df.writeStream
      .outputMode("append")
      .format("console")
      .start()

    // some statement 
    // some statement 

    query.awaitTermination();
```

will throw given exception and will close your streaming driver.

Comment: Worked for me using Java structured streaming. I had no `//some statement`s at all - just saved the StreamingQuery to a variable and then immediately called `sQueryVar.start()` and encountered the same problem. This solved it - thanks!

Comment: Does anyone know what the cause of this is? Why do the additional lines between the start() and the awaitTermination() cause an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly remove  `ds1.collect.foreach(println)` and   `ds1.printSchema()` , use `outputMode` and `awaitAnyTermination` for background process  Waiting until any of the queries on the associated  `spark.streams` has terminated

```
val spark = SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount")
    .config("spark.master", "local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()

  val ds1 = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    .option("subscribe", "topicA")  .load()

  val consoleOutput1 = ds1.writeStream
     .outputMode("update")
     .format("console")
     .start()

  spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

---

```
|key|value|topic|partition|offset|
+---+-----+-----+---------+------+
+---+-----+-----+---------+------+
```

Comment: Sorry just out of curiosity: why kindly? You are answering OP's question, not requesting :)

Comment: this is mentioning that there is no data coming from kafka. Please try to send data from that topic

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolves this issue by following code. In my scenario, I had multiple intermediate Dataframes, which were basically the transformations made on the inputDF.

```
 val query = joinedDF
      .writeStream
      .format("console")
      .option("truncate", "false")
      .outputMode(OutputMode.Complete())
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()
```

joinedDF is the result of the last transformation performed.

Comment: This works if you have a series of transformations, but if you have an intermediate action you're screwed

Comment: @Mehdi LAMRANI yeah.Thats why i mentioned my usage of this option.

Comment: I am trying to solve the latter as I stumbled upon this post, hence my comment :)