# How do you call multiple writeStream operations within a single Spark Job?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to write a Spark Structured Streaming job that reads from a Kafka topic and writes to separate paths (after performing some transformations) via the `writeStream` operation. However, when I run the following code, only the first `writeStream` gets executed and the second is getting ignored.

```
df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2") \
  .option("subscribe", "topic1") \
  .load()

write_one = df.writeStream \
  .foreachBatch(lambda x, y: transform_and_write_to_zone_one(x,y)) \
  .start() \
  .awaitTermination()

// transform df to df2

write_two = df2.writeStream \
  .foreachBatch(lambda x, y: transform_and_write_to_zone_two(x,y)) \
  .start() \
  .awaitTermination()
```

I initially thought that my issue was related to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41492614), however, after changing my code to the following:

```
df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2") \
  .option("subscribe", "topic1") \
  .load()

write_one = df.writeStream \
  .foreachBatch(lambda x, y: transform_and_write_to_zone_one(x,y)) \
  .start() 

// transform df to df2 
 
write_two = df2.writeStream \
  .foreachBatch(lambda x, y: transform_and_write_to_zone_two(x,y)) \
  .start()

write_one.awaitTermination()
write_two.awaitTermination()
```

I received the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
```

I am not sure why the additional code between `start()` and `awaitTermination()` would cause the error above (but I think this is probably a separate issue that is referenced in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51617823/9667721) to the same post above). What is the correct way to call multiple `writeStream` operations within the same job? Would it be best to have both of the writes within the function that is invoked by `foreachBatch` or is there are a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

Spark documentation says that in case you need perform writing into multiple locations you need to use `foreachBatch` method.

Your code should look something like:

```
streamingDF.writeStream.foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
  batchDF.persist()
  batchDF.write.format(...).save(...)  // location 1
  batchDF.write.format(...).save(...)  // location 2
  batchDF.unpersist()
}
```

*Note: `persist` in needed in order to prevent recomputations.*

You can check more: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch

Comment: Does this not imply that I would have a single checkpoint location for both writes? What if one of the writes fail but the other does not. Would it not be best to have separate checkpoints for each of the writes so that each can resume independently if failures occur?

Answer (score 1):

You just don't call `awaiTermination()` for each of your stream queries, but just one through spark session, eg:

`spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()`