# Reading kafka topic using spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql

I want to create dataframe on top of kafka topic and after that i want to register that dataframe as temp table to perform minus operation on data. I have written below code. But while querying registered table I'm getting error
"org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;"

```
org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType
org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "SERVER ******").option("subscribe", "TOPIC_NAME").option("startingOffsets", "earliest").load()

df.printSchema()

val personStringDF = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")

val user_schema =StructType(Array(StructField("OEM",StringType,true),StructField("IMEI",StringType,true),StructField("CUSTOMER_ID",StringType,true),StructField("REQUEST_SOURCE",StringType,true),StructField("REQUESTER",StringType,true),StructField("REQUEST_TIMESTAMP",StringType,true),StructField("REASON_CODE",StringType,true)))


val personDF = personStringDF.select(from_json(col("value"),user_schema).as("data")).select("data.*")

personDF.registerTempTable("final_df1")

spark.sql("select * from final_df1").show
```

ERROR:---------- "org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;"

Also i have used start() method and I'm getting below error.

20/08/11 00:59:30 ERROR streaming.MicroBatchExecution: Query final_df1 [id = 1a3e2ea4-2ec1-42f8-a5eb-8a12ce0fb3f5, runId = 7059f3d2-21ec-43c4-b55a-8c735272bf0f] terminated with error
java.lang.AbstractMethodError

NOTE: My main objective behind writing this script is i want to write minus query on this data and want to compare it with one of the register table i have on cluster. So , to summarise If I'm sending 1000 records in kafka topic from oracle database, I'm creating dataframe on top of oracle table , registering it as temp table and same I'm doing with kafka topic. Than i want to run minus query between source(oracle) and target(kafka topic). to perform 100% data validation between source and target. (Registering kafka topic as temporary table is possible?)

Comment: Hi, Welcome Parth to the tech community. You could refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40609771/queries-with-streaming-sources-must-be-executed-with-writestream-start

Answer (score 3):

Use `memory` sink instead of registerTempTable. Check below code.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType
org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val df = spark
.readStream
.format("kafka")
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "SERVER ******")
.option("subscribe", "TOPIC_NAME")
.option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
.load()

df.printSchema()

val personStringDF = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")

val user_schema =StructType(Array(StructField("OEM",StringType,true),StructField("IMEI",StringType,true),StructField("CUSTOMER_ID",StringType,true),StructField("REQUEST_SOURCE",StringType,true),StructField("REQUESTER",StringType,true),StructField("REQUEST_TIMESTAMP",StringType,true),StructField("REASON_CODE",StringType,true)))


val personDF = personStringDF.select(from_json(col("value"),user_schema).as("data")).select("data.*")


personDF
.writeStream
.outputMode("append")
.format("memory")
.queryName("final_df1").start()

spark.sql("select * from final_df1").show(10,false)
```

Comment: After using start() method, I'm getting Error:--- 20/08/11 00:59:30 ERROR streaming.MicroBatchExecution: Query final_df1 [id = 1a3e2ea4-2ec1-42f8-a5eb-8a12ce0fb3f5, runId = 7059f3d2-21ec-43c4-b55a-8c735272bf0f] terminated with error
java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Comment: Also, My main objective behind writing this script is i want to write minus query on this data and want to compare it with one of the register table i have on cluster. So , to summarise If I'm sending 1000 records in kafka topic from oracle database, I'm creating dataframe on top of oracle table , registering it as temp table and same I'm doing with kafka topic. Than i want to run minus query between source(oracle) and target(kafka topic). to perform 100% data validation between source and target.

Comment: ```memory``` source is not for production use case & think for alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Streaming DataFrame doesn't support the `show()` method. When you call `start()` method, it will start a background thread to stream the input data to the sink, and since you are using ConsoleSink, it will output the data to the console. You don't need to call `show()`.

remove the below lines,

```
personDF.registerTempTable("final_df1")
spark.sql("select * from final_df1").show
```

and add the below or equivalent lines instead,

```
val query1 = personDF.writeStream.queryName("final_df1").format("memory").outputMode("append").start()
query1.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: After using above method , use of start(), I'm getting below error. Error:------ 20/08/11 00:59:30 ERROR streaming.MicroBatchExecution: Query final_df1 [id = 1a3e2ea4-2ec1-42f8-a5eb-8a12ce0fb3f5, runId = 7059f3d2-21ec-43c4-b55a-8c735272bf0f] terminated with error
java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Comment: Also, My main objective behind writing this script is i want to write minus query on this data and want to compare it with one of the register table i have on cluster. So , to summarise If I'm sending 1000 records in kafka topic from oracle database, I'm creating dataframe on top of oracle table , registering it as temp table and same I'm doing with kafka topic. Than i want to run minus query between source(oracle) and target(kafka topic). to perform 100% data validation between source and target.